# How to refresh dependencies with Gradle in Android Studio (refresh button missing in Gradle window)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Gradle tool window shows like this in Android Studio 4.1.2

[image]

However according to InteliJ documentation it should had a refresh button

[InteliJ documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.3/jetgradle-tool-window.html)

Is there any other way to refresh the dependencies?

I have tried from terminal gradle build but it does not bring the new dependency in.

Maybe it has to do with my dependency?

Here is my gradle module file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "employee.android"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.3'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}

implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1' is the new dependency that I need and can not get in my project
```

Answer (score 3):

Alright messing around with everything I found the solution.

It seems that for Android-Studio there isn't a refresh button in gradle window.

Another button exists for that reason outside of gradle window.

[image]

After that everything works again.

Answer (score 0):

Call gradle or the gradle wrapper with the `--refresh-dependencies` parameter.

For example (Linux/Mac): `./gradlew assembleDebug --refresh-dependencies`